# How can I access the data in this JSON structure from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to use an API to get data in JSON form and pass it along to jQuery to do with it what I please.

My JSON looks like

```
{
    "username": {
        "id": 0001,
        "name": "test",
        "IconId": 000,
        "Level": 00,
        "revisionDate": 00000000
    }
}
```

From the PHP side this is my code

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_encode($json);
```

And from my jQuery I can get data by using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ar = <?php echo $json ?>;
  document.write(ar);
</script>
```

However, I want to be able to get specific data from the JSON. name for example.

I tried using jQuery.parseJSON like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ar = <?php echo $json ?>;
  ar = jQuery.parseJSON(ar);
  document.write(ar.name);
</script>
```

And I also tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ar = <?php echo $json ?>;
  ar = jQuery.parseJSON(ar);
  document.write(ar[0].name);
</script>
```

I always either get absolutely nothing (blank page), or I get "undefined".

Thank you.

Comment: Try document.write(ar.username.name);

Comment: You have to also reference the `"username"` present in the data. `document.write(ar.username.name)`. – [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Try document.write(ar[0].username.name);

Comment: `ar` is already an object. `jQuery.parseJSON` can only be used for *strings* containing JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data={
    "username": {
        "id": 0001,
        "name": "test",
        "IconId": 000,
        "Level": 00,
        "revisionDate": 00000000
    }
}

console.log(data["username"]["name"]);

//output test
```

Comment: This works great, thank you!

Comment: have you tried `JSON.parse`. Your response must be string.

Answer (score 0):

`ar` is your object reference. From there, that object has a single property called `username`. That property stores an object, which has a property called: `name`.

So, you need:

```
ar.username.name
```